# Cannot find module 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

I'm attempting to integrate React into an existing web page. At this time, I'm unable to get my React app loaded. My React app has two files. At this time, they look like this:

**myApp.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import MyComponent from './components/myComponent';

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**myComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('here');
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello (from React)</h2>
        <br />          
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

As you can see, I'm using ES6. I'm determined to use ES6 on this project. For that reason, I'm using Babel in my Gulp file to bundle my React app. I'm using Gulp instead of Webpack because my site is already using Gulp. Still, the relevant details in my package.json file look like this:

**package.json**

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
  "babelify": "^7.3.0",
  "browserify": "^13.1.0",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
  "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.11",
  "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
  "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
}
```

I then bundle my React app using the following task:

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('buildApp', function() {
    return browserify({ entries: ['./app/myApp.js', './app/components/myComponent.js'] })
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))        
    ;
});
```

When the above task is ran, the bundle.js file gets generated. It looks like this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _reactDom = require('react-dom');

var _reactDom2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reactDom);

var _myComponent = require('./components/myComponent');

var _myComponent2 = _interopRequireDefault(_myComponent);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

_reactDom2.default.render(_react2.default.createElement(NyComponent, null), document.getElementById('root'));

},{"./components/myComponent":2,"react":"react","react-dom":"react-dom"}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _reactDom = require('react-dom');

var _reactDom2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reactDom);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var MyComponent = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(MyComponent, _React$Component);

  function MyComponent() {
    _classCallCheck(this, MyComponent);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (MyComponent.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(MyComponent)).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(MyComponent, [{
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      console.log('here');
      return _react2.default.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        _react2.default.createElement(
          'h2',
          null,
          'Hello (from React)'
        ),
        _react2.default.createElement('br', null)
      );
    }
  }]);

  return MyComponent;
}(_react2.default.Component);

exports.default = MyComponent;

},{"react":"react","react-dom":"react-dom"}]},{},[1]);
```

Then, in the web page that I'm trying to load this app into, I have the following:

```
...
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
...
```

When I load attempt to load this in the browser, my React app does not load. I can see in the console window the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'
```

I don't understand why react isn't getting loaded.

Comment: @AndrewL. - This code sample was. However, my actual code has it typed correctly. Mistake in formatting on my part. I've fixed the question. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your package.json doesn't have React in it.  It's pretty hard for your project to use a package you haven't installed.

Just add: `"react": "^15.3.1"` to your package.json and do  a new npm install, and you should be fine.

Comment: Is it the same error, or is it now complaining about ReactDom (which is also missing in your package.json)?

Comment: Also double check that you don't have multiple package.json files in different directories.  If so, they each must have react specified.

Answer (score 33):

You are planning to use react inside typescript. Try this

```
npm install --save react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Answer (score 10):

Do `npm install react` in your local directory.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Gatsby and React was in my *package.json* with the following:

```
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
```

It was previously working when I ran `gatsby develop`. However, when I installed a couple of plugins (`npm install --save less gatsby-plugin-less`), the "Error: Cannot find module 'react'" started popping up whenever whenever I did `gatsby develop`.

Weirdly, I just did `npm install` on the *package.json* folder and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I Was facing this issue and in my case, I was referring a .env file and it was missing from my repo. Bring back the file and it works. Make sure to check these types of files that you are using in your project. There is no clear error message.

Answer (score 0):

There was another `package.json` file in the parent directory of the project which was causing this issue.
Once I deleted those and reinstalled packages, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
```

Type the above again after deleting  and don't let it auto import ie, type it fully. I know this seems naive but it worked for me several times. It has something to do with ide.

Answer (score 0):

the technical answer would be to run

`npm install --save react react-dom` / `yarn add react react-dom`

but if you just ran `create-react-app` those should have been installed automatically and something probably went wrong. Try and follow [these](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) steps as close as possible.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
> install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove
> create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot about babel require in your myApp.js

```
const React = require('react');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same type of error while using Parcel and React. I deleted the .parcel-cache and dist folder and started the build process again. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

`yarn add react react-redux` that fixed it for me

Comment: React and react-redux are different.